# Using cmd processes python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to get my basic python script to open and to write to and read to a cmd in order to allow it to send commands into noxplayer. I am trying to use sub processes and have discovered and read about using PIPES and not using them. Either way I can get it to send input with it resulting in a series of different breakpoints. Here are 2 examples of code I have tried.

```py
class bot:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def start(self):
        #open app and command prompt
        androidArg1 = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin/Nox.exe"
        androidArg2 = "-clone:Nox_" + str(self.num)
        androidArgs = [androidArg1, androidArg2]
        cmdArg1 = 'cmd'
        cmdArgs = [cmdArg1]
        self.app = subprocess.Popen(androidArgs)
        self.cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmdArgs, shell=True)

        self.cmd.communicate(input="cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin")
        while True:
            self.devices = self.cmd.communicate(input="nox_adb devices")
            print(self.devices)
```

is printing out `C:\Users\thePath>` but never finishes the first communication

```py
class bot:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def start(self):
        #open app and command prompt
        androidArg1 = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin/Nox.exe"
        androidArg2 = "-clone:Nox_" + str(self.num)
        androidArgs = [androidArg1, androidArg2]
        cmdArg1 = 'cmd'
        cmdArgs = [cmdArg1]
        self.app = subprocess.Popen(androidArgs)
        self.cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmdArgs, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
        stdout, stderr = self.cmd.communicate()
        stdout, stderr


        self.cmd.communicate(input="cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin")
        while True:
            self.devices = self.cmd.communicate(input="nox_adb devices")
            print(self.devices)
```

throws

```
Cannot send input after starting communication
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`communicate` is great because it is able to read standard output and error separately.

But otherwise it's pretty clunky as it sends the input only once. So as soon as this happens:

```
stdout, stderr = self.cmd.communicate()
```

it's over, you cannot send more input to your process.

Another way would be:

- feed input line by line to the process
- merge standard output and error (to avoid deadlocks)

but here it would be overkill. What's overkill in the first place is to `Popen` on a Windows `cmd` process when you don't need it *at all*. plus the `cd` command, plus the input feed, plus the `shell=True` ...

*make it simple*

Instead, use `Popen` directly on the `nox` command in the loop (with a small delay in between the calls maybe).

I didn't test that, but this is a self-contained way to running a command with an argument, in a given directory, repeatedly, and read its output.

```
import time,subprocess
while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["nox_adb","devices"],cwd="C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    devices = p.stdout.read().decode()
    rc = p.wait()   # wait for process to end & get return code
    if rc:
       break  # optional: exit if nox_adb command fails
    time.sleep(1)
```

if `nox_adb` is a `.bat` file that isn't going to cut it, in which case prefix the command by `cmd /c`:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(["cmd","/c","nox_adb","devices"],cwd="C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

this is roughly equivalent to adding `shell=True` on Windows, but `shell=True` is a lazy way of solving an issue that comes back in your head like a boomerang years later so better avoid it in industrial solutions.

Comment: Thank you I was defiantly overthinking it. The code you provided ```p = subprocess.Popen(["nox_adb","devices"],cwd="C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)``` is throwing can't find file so I changed it to ```subprocess.Popen(['cmd', "nox_adb", "devices"], cwd="C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)``` and that is working but gets stuck on ```p.stdout.read().decode()``` and never moves on to the next line of code.

Comment: nox_adb is probably a `.bat` file. In which case just use `shell=True` instead of `cmd` else the command never ends. or `["cmd","/c","nox_adb.bat","devices"]` without `shell=True` is even better